# Images not centered in larger card div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The images won't center on my cards. If I make the containers smaller they look fine on PC (centered) but on responsive they revert back to the larger size and are left aligned. I would like the images in the card containers to center regardless of container size.

I've tried changing the display:inline-block to display:block and class="text center" as well as .mx-auto but nothing seems to be working. Here's a link to the whole page http://www.wisbechinlinespeed.co.uk/committee-test.htm

```css
.row .heading .heading-icon {
  display: block;
}

.committee-card .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 0;
}

.committee-card .card {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #d5d5d5;
  margin: 0 0 28px;
}

.committee-card .card figure {
  width: 148px;
  height: 148px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.committee-card .card img {
  width: 148px;
  height: 148px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="committee-card padding-lg">
  <div class="containera">
<ul class="row">
  <li class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card equal-height" style="height: 349px;">
      <figure>
        <img src="committee/001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </figure>

      <h1>Richard Garwell</h1>
      <br />
      <p>Trustee and Track Committee Member</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card equal-height" style="height: 349px;">
      <figure>
        <img src="committee/002.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </figure>

      <h1>Glen Brown</h1>
      <br />
      <p>Trustee and Chairman</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="card equal-height" style="height: 349px;">
      <figure>
        <img src="committee/003.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
      </figure>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**stackoverflow says I am not allowed to post images, so you have to click out the link below to view the instructions**

Is this what you want it to be?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl837.png)

I saw flexbox in your code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKURL.png)

So why don't you just add **align-items: center;** to your whole container.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXJHa.png)

Comment: Your suggestion worked! I removed float:left and changed this line .committee-card .card{ 
  align-items:center; width:100%; 
   background:#fff; 
   padding:30px 20px; 
   text-align:center; 
   border:2px solid #d5d5d5;
   margin: 0 0 28px;
}

Comment: Thank you so much! It's always something simple! Much appreciated :-)

Comment: @JoTidman You're welcome! But could you please set this to the best answer or something? I just want to have it lol

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the width in `.committee-card .card figure` and the image will respect the alignment you've set in `.committee-card .card`

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `align-items-center` for the cards.

Bootstrap `card`´s `flex-direction` is `column`. Hence, you need to use `align-items-center`. Otherwise, you would have used `justify-content-center`.

```
<div class="card align-items-center" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```